# Encoding Error (5) using $cordovaFile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using ngCordova and specifically the module [$cordovaFile](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/) to remove a file from a specific location. More specific, I want to remove an image, which I saved before using [this tutorial](http://devdactic.com/how-to-capture-and-store-images-with-ionic/).

This works fine as my image is saved in the folder (iOS):

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/[APP_ID]/Library/NoCloud/
```

Note that using `cordova.file.dataDirectory` I can also get this location.

Now I have an image of which I have the `nativeURL` in the format as shown above:

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/[APP_ID]/Library/NoCloud/imagename.jpg
```

(the url is valid as it displays the image in the DOM when I use the `<img ng-src="nativeURL"`> tag).

I am trying to delete this image using the following syntax - but that throws me an [encoding error 5](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md#list-of-error-codes-and-meanings). Any thoughts how to solve it?

```
var removeFile = function(nativeURL) {

        var name = nativeURL.substr(nativeURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);        

        $cordovaFile.checkFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory, name)
        .then(function (success) {

            window.alert("file found " + success)

            $cordovaFile.removeFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory, name)
            .then(function (success) {
                // success
                window.alert("file deleted " + success)
            }, function (error) {
                // error
                window.alert("file not deleted error " + error)
            });

        }, function (error) {
        // error - here I get the ENCODING_ERR 5
            window.alert("file not found " + JSON.stringify(error))

        });

    }
```

Comment: Hey, what line is the error on?

Comment: Hey, sorry I see where you commented on the error. Is the 'file not found' alert firing?

Comment: do a log or alert on cordova.file.dataDirectory to make sure that is printing out /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/[APP_ID]/Library/NoCloud/   and you mite as well do one on 'name' to make sure it is returning imagename.jpg

Comment: Hey, yes indeed thats where it is firing. Logging returns a path with file:// in front of /var/... Do you think that is the reason? The imagename etc is correct as I can display the image in my DOM.

Comment: Hey, I am going to answer below (but it's not a real answer) because its easier than typing long comments here.

Answer (score 1):

So yeah, I would see if you could get that 'file://' removed, I would suspect that checkFile function doesn't know what to do with that that. Before you deal with getting that removed (I'm not sure how it got on there, if this works, you'll have to work backwards a little bit to find it.), you can just test it by setting

```
 var name = nativeURL.substr(nativeURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);        
 var file = /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/[APP_ID]/Library/NoCloud/imagename.jpg;

 $cordovaFile.checkFile(file, name)...
```

The only reason I wanted you to alert the 'name' is because I wasn't sure the substr() function was doing exactly what you want, but it probably is.

Comment: If you look in their guides, then they show as an example that you should use cordova.file.dataDirectory (http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/)

Comment: Wish i could help more:/ I am working on cordova/ionic right now but haven't gotten into this stuff

Answer (score -4):

From my research this appears to be a defect in the `$cordovaFile.removeFile` method. I have not found any solution as of yet.